# "Content-Type" for HEAD request

Tags: rest, http, http-headers, content-type

I'm building a REST API. Before calling a GET endpoint a HEAD request should be sent.

What kind of "Content-Type" parameter should a HEAD request provide?

Comment: If you mean HEAD *response* -- the same as for GET. BTW, come on, just look into the HTTP specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not mandatory to send `HEAD` request before sending `GET` request. 
 The `HTTP HEAD` method requests the headers that would be returned if the `HEAD` request's URL was instead requested with the `HTTP GET` method. `HEAD` request/response have no body so there is no need of Content-Type header

Comment: Is not here a contradiction around this Content-Type? Headers at GET would return something like 'application/json'. I want to know what exactly is returned, how big is that etc. Content-Type should refer to GET request and not to HEAD itself

Comment: HEAD request return header information of GET request only but without body, If you want to get content-length, your GET request should return it in response header, then it will appear in HEAD response header.